# Access local stack of linux threads (pthreads)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, stack

I'm currently implementing an application that makes use of multithreading but has requirements on the total memory consumption. I'd like to have a master thread doing I/O and several workers doing computations.

Currently I'm having several datastructures on the masters stack that are accessed by the workers. I use OpenMP for work distribution. As the master/worker pattern doesn't work well with OpenMP I'd like to use pthreads for multithreading.

I know that each thread maintains a local stack, but what exactly will happening to the stack on thread creation?

Are datastructures that lie on the master's stack accessible by the workers or should I move them to the heap? 
I'd also like to avoid duplication of data but don't know if new threads will create a local copy of the masters stack.

---

Edit: found the answer myself ...

After reading into the details of the clone() system call that is used by pthreads I realized that all threads share the complete virtual memory. This means that although threads use their own stack, the memory regions that are used for each stack are still shared.

I wrote some code to verify that behaviour:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* increment(void* value) {
        int* val = (int*) value;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                ++(*val);
        }
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        int stackvar = 0;

        pthread_t thread1, thread2;
        int iret1, iret2;

        iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, increment, (void*) &stackvar );
        iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, increment, (void*) &stackvar );

        pthread_join( thread1, NULL );
        pthread_join( thread2, NULL );

        printf("%i\n", stackvar);

        return 0;
}
```

As output is "200" the threads manipulated the stack of their parent thread successfully.

I think most ressources on the internet dont't express this fact correctly. 
Threads *do* share the stack in the sense of shared memory, but the stackpointer of each thread is private. For each thread a part of the *shared* memory is assigned as local stack.

This also means that it doesn't matter if the parent thread has large data structures on the stack, as memory is never duplicated for threading.

Comment: You're right, I was wrong. Each thread will start with the new separate stack and not with the copy of the parent's stack, if you use `pthread_create`. You should post your edit as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can share your stacks, as you explain.  In general, however, you should not, except in a few special circumstances.  Your example program has data races, and so the output will only be 200 through pure luck (perhaps because your operating system doesn't actually schedule the children to run simultaneously.)

One special circumstance where it does make sense to share the stack is when the parent creates some interesting data structure, and then passes it to its children, who access the data structure *read only*.

Other than data races, here's another thing that can go wrong with sharing on the stack instead of the heap.  The parent can return from the procedure where it created the child threads, so the stack data may not stay valid for the lifetime of the child thread.  So you should only share stack data if the `pthread_create()` call and the matching `pthread_join()` call are in the same scope (as they are in your example.)

Comment: In my scenario I'd like to have a work queue on the parent's stack and the threads will be joined in the same scope the work queue was created. Access to the queue will be synchronized. I guess that's fine to do.